# Transforming coordinates from one CRS to another with rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I'm trying to merge some rasters with `rasterio.merge.merge`. They are in the same CRS, EPSG:3857. I want the merged raster to cover the whole earth. Exactly the range (in coordinates): `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = -180.0225, -90.0225, 179.9775, 90.0225`.

The problem is that when using the `bounds` parameter of this function I have to give these limits in the same CRS of the rasters. How can I convert the tuple `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax` from regular coordinates to projected coordinates in EPSG:3857?

Comment: For EPSG:4326 or OGC::CRS84 the whole Earth extents are limited to +/-180 for longitude and +/-90 for Latitude

Answer (score 5):

This is how to achieve CRS transformation using `rasterio` (and optionally `shapely`):

```py
import rasterio.warp
from rasterio.crs import CRS

# In GeoJSON format
x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = bounds
feature = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
       [[x_max, y_min], 
        [x_max, y_max], 
        [x_min, y_max], 
        [x_min, y_min], 
        [x_max, y_min]]
   ]
}

# Project the feature to the desired CRS
feature_proj = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
    CRS.from_epsg(4326),
    CRS.from_epsg(3857),
    feature
)
```

With the latest version of rasterio (tested with 1.2+) you can also use `shapely`, which simplify the code:

```py
import rasterio.warp
from rasterio.crs import CRS
from shapely.geometry import box

# Project the feature to the desired CRS
feature_proj = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
    CRS.from_epsg(4326),
    CRS.from_epsg(3857),
    box(*bounds)
)
```

Comment: GeoJSON is not EPSG:4326

Answer (score 2):

simply transform your bb as 2 corners using `pyproj`:

```py
from pyproj import CRS
from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 3857)

xmin, ymin = transformer.transform(-180.0225, -90.0225)
xmax, ymax = transformer.transform(179.9775, 90.0225)
```

Answer (score 2):

For reasons discussed [here](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/2222) and with the introduction of [rasterio.warp.transform_bounds](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.warp.html#rasterio.warp.transform_bounds) I think the way to do this would be:

```
from rasterio.warp import transform_bounds

bounds = (-180.0225, -90.0225, 179.9775, 90.0225)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = transform_bounds(sar_img_crs.to_epsg(), 4326, *bounds)
```

Also, the answer by Pierrick above needs the `always_xy=True` flag to be set in the `transformer.transform` call for it to return values in the correct order.

Comment: The correct order for EPSG:4326 would be -90, -180, 90, 180