# Getting UTM coordinates from TIFF

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, utm

I am trying to extract UTM coordinates (in meters) of every pixel in a TIFF file using the following syntax in Python.

```
tifImage = rasterio.open(tif_file)
dx = tifImage.transform[0]
dy = tifImage.transform[4]
ulx = tifImage.transform[2]
uly = tifImage.transform[5]
```

Then I can calculate UTM of any pixel by using pixel location, width of each pixel and upper left pixel location.

In some files I get correct UTM values as a set of numbers in meters (EW: 789522.5815   NS: 2364415.745) but in some other files, I am getting numbers that seem to be decimal representations of GPS Lat/Longs like (18.8202568671686, 74.0741268192744) and not the UTM values.

How can I address this? I would like to get the coordinates for all the TIFF files. I could not quite figure out the CRS argument and may be that is something I need to do.

Would you recommend to use GDAL?

Comment: Your raster with the low values is in a geographic coordinate system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system, UTM is a projected coordinate system https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/gcs_vs_pcs/. You need to find out which geographic coordinate system your raster is in, most likely WGS84/geographic EPSG:4326 https://epsg.io/4326 which would make the UTM zone 43 north. You can project the coordinate, have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402154/transforming-coordinates-from-one-crs-to-another-with-rasterio.

Answer (score 1):

You can reproject your lon, lat coordinates to UTM. Here's an example of grabbing the x, y coords in raster CRS, then reprojecting to UTM.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio

# My UTM CRS is Zone 55 South,
# find yours on epsg.io or from an existing dataset in correct projection
utm_crs = 28355

with rio.open(f"raster.tif", "r") as ds:

    crs = ds.crs
    cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ds.width), np.arange(ds.height))
    xs, ys = rio.transform.xy(ds.transform, rows, cols)

# Create reprojected point geometries
points = gpd.points_from_xy(xs[0], ys[0], crs=crs).to_crs(utm_crs)

# Make a simple list
xys = [[p.x, p.y] for p in points] 

print(xys)
```

Credit for using a numpy meshgrid to get coordinates using rasterio.transform.xy without looping from [this answer by @intotecho](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415754/2856)